# How wrap shapes(not blend) to a path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, chart-design

I was trying to create a data visualization with this style in illustrator

[image]

by using these shapes from a chart data

[image]

Obviously you can create this using blend tools and path, however, if it's from a chart or data, it should be as close as possible. I can manually adjust the shape but if its like 100-200 lines, it's going to be time consuming and wouldn't be accurate.

I wonder if there's an easy way.

[image]

Comment: this really depends on what you consider easy. its really just a for loop which is easy by some measure. another way is to make them strokes (not rectangles) make a brush apply on path expand.

Comment: @joojaa thanks, but the problem with the brush is that it replicates the group to fit the whole path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an Art Brush to do this. You will need to make each line a single stroke though, and you'll need to create an empty spacer at the end of the brush. If you have all the data in a raster image of the graph, you could use Image tracing using the Outline trace option to actually create the lines.

[image]

Anyway, here's an example

A brush like this shown here. I've used a repeating pattern here for the sake of convenience, but you don't have to. Each stroke can be any height.

[image]

Applied to a circle as an Art Brush

[image]

It can also be applied to just part of a circle, here I added some anchors to delete some segments of the circle

[image]

Comment: thanks! this actually worked! I also tried using different shapes and the shapes didn't duplicate.

Comment: @christopher essentially the same as i said.